# How to call "echo ${GOPATH}" with call-process?

Tags: shell, call-process

I try to execute `echo ${GOPATH}` with `call-process` as below:

```
(call-process "echo" nil t nil "${GOPATH}")
```

But it only output "${GOPATH}" not the value of that value. Would anyone please let me know what the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `(call-process-shell-command "echo ${GOPATH}" nil t nil)`. In this case, `${PATH}` is syntax defined by a shell, not a native call, so you'll need to invoke a shell to interpret it.

However, you may be interested in `(insert (getenv "GOPATH"))` which is considerably more direct, as it simply reads the environment instead of spawning a shell to read the environment in its stead.

Comment: Good answer, but note that the environment Emacs sees is not necessarily the environment that your shell sees (generally depending on how and where Emacs is invoked).

Comment: @phils ah. Thanks for reminding me. I always spawn Emacs from a shell, so I forget.